# Execute sql 92 query on message queue

Tags: mq, spring-jms, ansi-sql-92

I want to retrieve messages sent in a queue between two PutTime.
 I try with this query:

```
TextMessage vMessage = (TextMessage)  
  super.receiveSelected("Root.MQMD.PutDate = '"+pPutDate+"' 
         AND Root.MQMD.PutTime BETWEEN CAST('103345' AS TIME) AND CAST('104345' AS TIME)");
```

But I have a message selector syntax exception. What's wrong with this query ?

```
org.springframework.jms.InvalidSelectorException: JMSWMQ2008: 
Impossible to open the message queue.
It's caused by the the bad syntax of the query
```

Comment: You need to show us exception's message.

Comment: The exception's message is org.springframework.jms.InvalidSelectorException: JMSWMQ2008: Impossible to open the message queue. It's caused by the the bad syntax of the query